# Check whether the timestamps is between are between two columns

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I need to check whether a timestamp range is within the timestamp range from two field in the database.

I have 2019-09-02 09:20:00 and 2019-09-02 09:28:00 in the database.

I need to check whether 2019-09-02 09:22:00 and 2019-09-02 10:40:00 is between the above time range.

**---update---**

following is the query I used.

```
self.cursor.execute(
        "SELECT * FROM time_tracker.time_tracker_details WHERE((created_time  <= %s AND stopped_time >= %s) OR (created_time  >= %s AND stopped_time <= %s))"
        "ORDER BY created_time ASC",
        [str(created_time), str(stopped_time), str(created_time), str(stopped_time)])
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: what is the return result?

Comment: nothing is returned

Comment: Please provide  some sample data, you are4 selecting every datetime that is before and after all of your time stamps. so i guess your Select statement is flawed. because the provided Id doesn'T exist or parent_tt_id is not empty at least for the provided user_id

Comment: no. those are some additional filters.. i have corrected the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally found what I was hoping for

```
SELECT * FROM time_tracker.time_tracker_details WHERE parent_tt_id = '' AND user_id = %s AND 
(( %s >= created_time  AND stopped_time >= %s)) OR (created_time  >= %s AND stopped_time <= %s)
OR  ( %s >= created_time AND ( %s <= stopped_time AND stopped_time <= %s)) 
OR (( %s <= created_time  AND created_time <= %s) AND stopped_time >= %s)) 
ORDER BY tt_id ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try changing OR for AND, where dates are greater than created_time and less than stop_time

example:

```
AND ((created_time  <= %s AND created_time <= %s) AND (stopped_time >= %s AND stopped_time >= %s))
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not entirely clear to me what you want to test whether both dates are between `created_time` and `stopped_time` or whether one of them is.

The answer below asumes you want to test whether *BOTH* dates are within the range (`started_time`-`stopped_time`)

Actually there is a keyword `BETWEEEN` in SQL which I find really describtive. You can use it like that

```
..WHERE (%s BETWEEN created_time AND stopped_time) AND (%s BETWEEN created_time AND stopped_time)
```

To improve readability; Keep in mind `BETWEEN` is inclusive, what you require here.

[BETWEEN DOCS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)